# TypeError: value.push is not a function with Angularjs $resource query

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I am returning a array of objects from the server:

```
[{id: 1, name: "name"},{id: 2, name: "name2"}]
```

Now I use angular-resource `$query` to fetch the data as it expects an array.
When the data is received I get this error:

```
TypeError: value.push is not a function
```

Is there an issue with the response I give from server=?

Source of error:

```
 // jshint +W018
                if (action.isArray) {
                  value.length = 0;
                  forEach(data, function(item) {
                    if (typeof item === "object") {
                      value.push(new Resource(item));
                    } else {
                      // Valid JSON values may be string literals, and these should not be converted
                      // into objects. These items will not have access to the Resource prototype
                      // methods, but unfortunately there
                      value.push(item);
                    }
                  });
                } else {
                  shallowClearAndCopy(data, value);
                  value.$promise = promise;
                }
              }
```

Controller:

```
var stream = [];
stream = new VideoStream({param: 'streamTypes'});
stream.$query();
```

Service:

```
app.service('DataService', [
    '$resource', 'Common', '$rootScope',
    function($resource, Common, $rootScope) {
        return $resource($rootScope.appWebRoot + "myUrl/:param", {param: '@param'},
        {

        });
    }
]);
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

VideoStream:

```
app.service('VideoStream', [
    '$resource', 'Common', '$rootScope',
    function($resource, Common, $rootScope) {
        return $resource($rootScope.appWebRoot + "videoStreams/api/:param",
        {param: '@param'},
        {

        });
    }
]);
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83452/discussion-between-grundy-and-kaspar).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are creating an instance of your resource as an object

```
var stream = [];
stream = new VideoStream({param: 'streamTypes'}); //This is the problem. $resource is expecting an array.
stream.$query(); //This is an instance method.

//All you need to do is:
var stream = [];
stream = VideoStream({param: 'streamTypes'}).query();
```

From [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource](http://ngDocs):

$resource returns:

> A resource "class" object with methods for the default set of resource
>   actions optionally extended with custom actions. The default set
>   contains these actions:
>
> ```
> { 'get':    {method:'GET'},
>   'save':   {method:'POST'},
>   'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
>   'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
>   'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
> ```
>
> Calling these methods invoke an $http with the specified http method,
>   destination and parameters. When the data is returned from the server
>   then the object is an instance of the resource class. The actions
>   save, remove and delete are available on it as methods with the $
>   prefix

Comment: Was this caused because I use .service instead of .factory?

Comment: @Kaspar, nope, seems this because instance can be mapped only to one object

Comment: The way $resource works is that when you define a $resource it returns a class with some class methods such as query and get. Calling those methods will create a new instance of your class. You don't need to `new` your class unless you have existing data that you want to transform into a resource class. More info at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Thank you for the info! Technically Grundy answered first with a solution that solved my problem. So Grundy, if you write a answer I can accept it, if you don't want to then I will accept Wawy,s answer.

Comment: @Kaspar, it was a simple guess :-) i think Wawy should add in answer some explaining from comments and docs, and you can accept it :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Wawy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3257857/wawy)'s answer, according to the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be
>   invoked with the following parameters:
>
> - HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], error])
> - non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
> - non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])

On checking the value of `VideoStream` in the controller, we find:

```
function Resource(value) {
      shallowClearAndCopy(value || {}, this);
    } // Actual Resource class object with regular action(s) we can work with
```

there

Calling `VideoStream({param: 'streamTypes'})` returns:

```
undefined // Cannot call anything of undefined
```

and `new VideoStream({param:'streamTypes'})` returns:

```
Resource {param: "streamTypes"}
// Instance of the Resource class (an object) where $action(s) are available
// Verified in the chrome console
```

With this in mind, the case should be:

```
var stream = [];
stream = VideoStream.query({param: 'streamTypes'});
```